# AccountDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 3003

Tags: anchor

I have a pda which I tried to increase the space without closing it first and not using `realloc`,

Is it possible to close this account without facing the `Error Code: AccountDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 3003. Error Message: Failed to deserialize the account.` error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to close the account using the initial account struct and space definition.

After closing it, I was able to `init` it with the new space requirements.

Comment: Could you provide the code that you used? Would be great to have it documented